# How to setup an interactive Python environment so that you can compile function/variable one by one or as a whole?

Tags: python, vim, ipython

I want to setup an python environment so that I can open python session on the on one side and a python file on the other side, and when I update a function or variable, I can re-compile it to the terminal to reflect the change. Something like:[image]

I use mac and I would like to stick with vim for python development.

I guess the thing on the left is ipython terminal?

Thanks for anyone who can point me to the right place or show me how!

Comment: You mean an integrated development environment (IDE)? Or simply an editor that runs your program whenever you save your changes? There are many options for both, the right one depends on your operatings system and personal taste. So what OS are you on? EDIT: you could also run the iPython notebook `ipython notebook`. This will open an interactive environemnt in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I use mac for my dev and I would like to develop my python work in vim. I used ipython notebook before and I would like to stick with vim for python development. Do you know how to setup the above environment in the screen shot?

Comment: Where did you snap that screenshot?

Comment: A tutorial called Deep Learning with TensorFlow, author: Dan Van Boxel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First step,** find the author's GitHub account:

https://github.com/dvbuntu/

**Second step,** find the author's `vimrc`:

https://github.com/dvbuntu/.files/blob/master/.vimrc

**Third step,** find a hint:

https://github.com/dvbuntu/.files/blob/master/.vimrc#L80-L85

**Fourth step,** find that tool:

https://github.com/epeli/slimux

**Fifth step,** read the `README`.

**Sixth step,** if the `README` seems promising, install the tool and configure it.

Comment: You can get to step five in a couple of minutes, tops! Try harder next time.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try harder next time!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need some tool like Spyder, Eric python IDE or can be like pycharm.

Here is screen from spyder:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and apologize to mention that I would like to stick with vim for development.